# Dynamic Qt-based XML settings manager

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dynamic, settings

I'd like to create a C++/Qt4.8.6-based GUI app for Windows which can help users modify XML settings. The application is a client which sends modified settings to server. Some nodes are represented as group box, others as spinboxes and so on. But the representation is fixed - I mean that the widget structure is predefined. Now I want more flexible widget. For example, I can add an attribute, which tells program about parameter type.

`<Item type="bool" name="Broadcast">true</Item>`

`bool` value will lead to `QCheckBox`, `mask` value will lead to a set of `QCheckBoxes` by default and so on. `type` attribute is used only on the client side. External file can be introduced to override default widgets in some cases.

What is typical approach for such dynamic things? Are there any libraries which can serve as a base for it? A minimum-intrusive modification of the current file format is preferred. So, the primary file will contain some anchors for GUI interpretation and more detailed description (like mapping between bool and checkbox, alignment and so on) can be stored separately. Qt 4 is preferred, but I don't mind against Qt 5.

Comment: So you want to show a GUI which is dynamically created based on the contents of an XML file? A possible way could be to perform an XML transformation to get a UI description which can be instantiated through [QUiLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html). If you can provide more details, it would help to suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: @m.s. Yes, you are right, I want GUI which is dynamically created based on the contents of an XML file. I will study `QUiLoader`.